# Why does a bound variable not work inside a FILTER in a UNION BLOCK?

Tags: sparql

The following query works as expected:

```
PREFIX nct: <http://n2t.net/ark:/39333/ncg/type#>
PREFIX ncv: <http://n2t.net/ark:/39333/ncg/vocab#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT ?label ?url WHERE {
  BIND("Chapel Hill" as ?placename)
  {
    ?marker 
      a nct:HistoricalMarker ;
      skos:prefLabel ?label ;
      skos:note ?markerDescription ;
    .
    FILTER CONTAINS(?markerDescription, "Chapel Hill")
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?musician skos:prefLabel ?label .
    ?place
      skos:prefLabel ?placename ;
      ncv:associatedWithAgent ?musician ;
    .
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?movie skos:prefLabel ?label .
    ?place
      skos:prefLabel ?placename ;
      ncv:filmingLocationFor ?movie ;
    .
  }
}
```

But if I change `FILTER CONTAINS(?markerDescription, "Chapel Hill")` in the first block to `FILTER CONTAINS(?markerDescription, ?placename)`, it no longer works.

[Try the working query.](https://jena-fuseki.fly.dev/#/dataset/NCG/query?query=PREFIX%20nct%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fn2t.net%2Fark%3A%2F39333%2Fncg%2Ftype%23%3E%0APREFIX%20ncv%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fn2t.net%2Fark%3A%2F39333%2Fncg%2Fvocab%23%3E%0APREFIX%20skos%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Flabel%20%3Furl%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20BIND%28%22Chapel%20Hill%22%20as%20%3Fplacename%29%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fmarker%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20nct%3AHistoricalMarker%20%3B%0A%20%20%09%20%20skos%3AprefLabel%20%3Flabel%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20skos%3Anote%20%3FmarkerDescription%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%09.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20CONTAINS%28%3FmarkerDescription%2C%20%22Chapel%20Hill%22%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fmusician%20skos%3AprefLabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20skos%3AprefLabel%20%3Fplacename%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ncv%3AassociatedWithAgent%20%3Fmusician%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fmovie%20skos%3AprefLabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20skos%3AprefLabel%20%3Fplacename%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ncv%3AfilmingLocationFor%20%3Fmovie%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

[Try the not working query.](https://jena-fuseki.fly.dev/#/dataset/NCG/query?query=PREFIX%20nct%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fn2t.net%2Fark%3A%2F39333%2Fncg%2Ftype%23%3E%0APREFIX%20ncv%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fn2t.net%2Fark%3A%2F39333%2Fncg%2Fvocab%23%3E%0APREFIX%20skos%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Flabel%20%3Furl%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20BIND%28%22Chapel%20Hill%22%20as%20%3Fplacename%29%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fmarker%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20nct%3AHistoricalMarker%20%3B%0A%20%20%09%20%20skos%3AprefLabel%20%3Flabel%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20skos%3Anote%20%3FmarkerDescription%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%09.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20CONTAINS%28%3FmarkerDescription%2C%20%3Fplacename%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fmusician%20skos%3AprefLabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20skos%3AprefLabel%20%3Fplacename%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ncv%3AassociatedWithAgent%20%3Fmusician%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fmovie%20skos%3AprefLabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20skos%3AprefLabel%20%3Fplacename%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ncv%3AfilmingLocationFor%20%3Fmovie%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Why?

Comment: SPARQL is evaluated bottom-up and the scope of variables is "from isnide to out." The scope of the `BIND` doesn't go into the `UNION`. See the specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#variableScope - the same would also be the case for `VALUES`

Comment: @UninformedUser If that's the case, then why does the variable get bound in the 2nd and 3rd parts of the `UNION`?

Comment: it does not get bound in part 2 and 3- you just think it is getting bound ... but, all what happens is that each part of the `UNION` is evaluated and then a join with your inline data of the `BIND` happens afterwards. This clearly doesn't work if you use that variable in the `FILTER` like in your first clause, because it is just not set yet which makes the `FILTER` fail

Comment: @UninformedUser OK, thanks. If you would put your explanation as an answer, I will accept it.